# AngularJS textaera enter key submit form with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

Hello i want to submit my form when i press enter inside my text aera.

My textarea have an autocomplete form created in a angularjs directive (autocompleteAngularExpression)

I have try this :

```
<textarea ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && submit()" 
id="inputId" autocomplete-angular-expression> 
</textaera>
```

The problem is that when i press enter in the autocomplete of my textarea i submit the form.

How can i submit the form only if the autocomplete form is showing ?

My directive is a little complex.

In the scope i have unparsed value

```
 directive('autocompleteAngularExpression', ['_', '$', function(_, $) {

        function split(val) {
            return val.split( /\s+/ );
        }

        function extractLast(term) {
            return term.split(/[()-\s]+/).pop();
        }

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                indexed : "=indexedValue",
                nonIndexedValue : "=nonIndexedValue"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                function containsSomeIndexed(words) {
                    return _.some(words, function(word) {
                        return _.contains(scope.indexedValue, word);
                    });
                }

                ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(expression) {
                    if (!expression || expression === "") {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('indexValid', true);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('indexValid', containsSomeIndexed(expression.split(/[()-:\s]+/)));
                    }
                    return expression;
                });

                element.autocomplete({
                    minLength: 1,
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        var sourceList;
                        if (containsSomeIndexed(request.term.split(/[()-:\s]+/))) {
                            sourceList = _.union(scope.indexedValue, scope.nonIndexedValue);
                        } else {
                            sourceList = scope.indexedValue;
                        }
                        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(sourceList, extractLast(request.term)));
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        var selectedValue = ui.item.value;
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        var partial = terms.pop();
                        var prependBuffer = "";
                        while (partial.charAt(0) === '(' || partial.charAt(0) === '-') {
                            prependBuffer = prependBuffer + partial.charAt(0);
                            partial = partial.substring(1, partial.length);
                        }
                        terms.push(prependBuffer + selectedValue);
                        return false;
                    }
              });
            }
        };
    }]).
```

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit confusing. If you could revise it and make it clear what your issue is and what you want to achieve, that'll help people to answer your question.

Comment: Can you show the code for `autocompleteAngularExpression` directive?

Comment: Show the    directive you created, maybe we will be able to modify it and the ng-enter directive to answer your requirement

Comment: @OrGuz the autocomplete directive is a little complex

Comment: @gregouille I would try to set a variable on the scope, which is true when the autocompletelist is opened and change the if statement on ng-enter to if(e.which === 13 && isAutocompleteOpened === false)

Comment: @gregouille please create a fiddle/plunkr that would be more better to help you

Answer (score 16):

Instead of doing `$event.keyCode == 13` each time write on directive `ng-enter`,
that  will do the trick for you.

Try

```
<textarea ng-enter="submit()" id="inputId" autocomplete-angular-expression> </textaera>
```

Add this directive to get `ngEnter`

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown", function(e) {
            if(e.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {'e': e});
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[**Reference Link**](https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884263)

Comment: Thank you pankajparkar, it is maybe cleaner this way. But the problem is : when i press enter in the autocomplete box the form is submit !

Comment: @gregouille you don't want to submit form on enter click?

Comment: @pankajparkar Ah, that's what I thought. Thanks, it's a nice thing actually. Learnt something new today :)